# How to change the post form from plugin?

Tags: plugins, posts, post-editor

I am starting making some wordpress plugin, so I am a beginer. I just wonder how can I change the post form of the pages. For example for adding some other input (of type file or text)? I am trying to use

```
add_filter('comments_template', 'add_new_fields');
```

but nothings happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change/add something to post form, you have to deal with meta boxes. I would recommend you to read through these articles:

- [Reusable Custom Meta Boxes Part 1: Intro and Basic Fields](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields/)
- [Reusable Custom Meta Boxes Part 2: Advanced Fields](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-2-advanced-fields/)
- [Reusable Custom Meta Boxes Part 3: Extra Fields](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-3-extra-fields/)
- [Reusable Custom Meta Boxes Part 4: Using the Data](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-4-using-the-data/)